# Accessibility: focus on a view

Tags: ios, swift, view, focus, accessibility

In my application (that has to be accessible for blind user) I have this scenario (its a grammatic exercise)

[image]

When I try it on a device turning on VoiceOver, first it focus on the first part of the sentence, so in that case it read "Kesha" and when i swipe right to read the next part it read the second part of the sentence "the contract because...". What I want is to make it also focus on the gray box (that is a `UIView`element) before it read the second part of the sentence, so that the user know where that empty box is in the sentence, but i don't know how to do that.

I alread tried `grayBox.accessibilityLabel = "empty box"` or `grayBox.accessibilityHint = "empty box"` but it just don't set the focus on that view and it doesn't speak. I also tried to put an empty `UILabel` inside the box but I have some issue positioning that in the right order and I don't think it is the right way to do it. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to reorder the views to be read out by VoiceOver as you wish, I suggest to take a look at https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#reading-order that may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `UIView` that you want to 'receive focus' you just need to enable accessibility or mark it as an accessible element, An example:

```
myGreyView.isAccessibilityElement = true
myGreyView.accessibilityLabel = "A grey box"
myGreyView.accessibilityHint = "this is a secretive box. I don't know what it does"
```

You can also tick a box in the UIView's properties in xcode interface builder "Accessibility Enabled" I think its called. Which also lets you set the label and hint.

For more information see this [Apple guide to VoiceOver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app)

Comment: Right here what I miss thanks, and any idea on how to set the right order of the "focus"? Because now the first thing that is read its that empty box, and than the first part of the sentence

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure on how to set the order, might have to read that guide

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the order of elements being read out. Is the first part and second part different UILabels or one label?

Are you adding these in code or Xib/Storyboard? Depending on the order they are  added as subviews can effect the order VoiceOver reads items out.

When adding the 3x UI elements add them in this order below.

1. UILabel - "Kesha"
2. UIView - Gray box, "A grey box"
3. UILabel - "the contract because it was not fair."

If you have added them via Interface builder (Xib/Storyboard) make sure the order is correct in the view hierarchy.

If this fails you could try overriding the method "accessibilityElements" and return an array of the labels and grey view in the order you want them read out.

Comment: I am adding them programmatically and the order I add the subviews doesn't seem to affect the order they being read. I have the same problem in another part of my application in which I show a popup view that has 2 labels and a button. Throught the command 'UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibility.Notification.screenChanged,  argument: self.popupLabel)' I am able to set the focus on the first label of the popup View when it shows up, but than using the accessibility gesture (the swipe) that should read the next label and then the button, it read the elements on the background instead